# SIGABRT when trying to run a second Target of my app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I added a second target to my project to be able to use the same Xcode project for multiple apps (flavors of the base app with minor changes). I renamed the target, changed the scheme to match the name, renamed the second info.plist as well. Now when I try to run the second target the app crashes with a SIGABRT on the splash screen. There are no logs whatsoever. An exception breakpoint or Swift error breakpoint doesn't help either. What could be causing this?

**EDIT:**
I don't know what caused the problem but I deleted the target and scheme. Then I re added everything and followed the same steps. Now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add breakpoint on all exception to get the line where code is going to crash

Here are the steps.

- Move to "Breakpoint Navigator".
- Click + symbol at bottom-left corner of navigator.

[image]

- You should see this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not for all case but in most of cases **SIGABRT** error occur when you are releasing object that already released in memory.

How can we detect where are you going to wrong? [Best way is do enable zombie object in your Xcode.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode)